# dynamically set the print area by visible content not formula

Tags: excel

I need to dynamically set the print area of a sheet (Sheet1!). Sheet1 is a summery sheet listing the content of multiple other sheets through an array formula, with content in col A:C. the number of rows are always different, so in order to have the print area height dynamically set to be according to the visible data, i entered a new name in Name Manager with this formula =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C:$C),3) named DynPrint. and the actual Print Area for Sheet1 I referred to =DynPrint. this should work, but the problem is that excel sees the array formula as content and therefor I'm getting 2000 rows printed out unless i'm manually resetting the print area before each print.

Thank You

Comment: Try: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,LOOKUP(2,1/($C:$C<>""),ROW($C:$C)),3)`

Comment: Wow, works good. If its not too hard can you please explain the syntax of your formula. Also, how am i marking this question as answered.

Comment: `LOOKUP(2,1/($C:$C<>""),ROW($C:$C))` finds the last cell that is not blank and returns the row number.